# Completion block for assets library read With Background Thread

Tags: ios, xcode4, objective-c-blocks

I'm Showing some Alert View like operation Don and then  after/below that I'm calling a method to read the Assets Lib images from assets libraray of iphone as in Backgroung thread. The completion handler to read the images is in the same fx which is running in background thread (Im printing Bool value with fx isMainThread). When control is inside the completion block of read images it starts executing the code in main thread. Why So?  Is completeion blocks runs in background thread or main thread.

IMP: This Completion blocks becoming in main thread happens only once or start of application launch when 1st time i m clicking for operation , It will not block UI after 1st operation.

Comment: Are you sure that first time you aren't calling the function from the main thread?

Comment: actually the function which I m calling in background thread. It is always in background thread. Inside the body of fx i have written the completeion block to read the assests. when first time the controls enters inside the completion block it is in main thread for all image/video assets and there is no background thread exists for further execution. But when second time it enters/executed the same code for same conditions it works fine. I debugged that problem by calling the method isOnMainThread method. It returns me the status of threads.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. Actually there is no problem with my code. The issue which i explained above is with the jailbreaker devices only. Other latest devices , the code is working fine.